# Solving SHM on Python

Tags: python, physics

I need to solve a simple harmonic oscillator system iteratively by using the Euler method. This is my code so far.

```
#importing necessary libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#defining constants
x_0 = 1e-10  #initial position
v_0 = 0  #initial velocity 
m_sodium = 3.82e-26   #mass of sodium atom
k = 12.2  #force constant

#function for potential energy
def potential(x):
    Vx = k * (x ** 2) / 2    
    return Vx


#equation angular frequency 
omega = np.sqrt(k / m_sodium)

#creating an array for time
t = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)


#initialising x and v arrays (to eventually hold the results)
x = np.zeros(len(t))
v = np.zeros(len(t))


#initial conditions
x[0] = x_0
v[0] = v_0


#defining time-step
dt = t[1] - t[0]


#Euler method to solve ODE for all the iterations
for i in range(1, len(t)):    
    x[i] = v[i] * dt
    v[i] = omega**2 * x[i] * dt    
                         
#plotting a graph x vs t

plt.plot(t, x)
plt.xlabel('Time t')
plt.ylabel('Position x')
plt.grid(True)
plt.title('Simple Harmonic Oscillator System')
```

I am meant to be obtaining a sinusoid wave, however instead I am obtaining the image I've attached. Could anyone point out what I'm doing wrongly please?

[image]

Comment: You start with `x[1] = v[1] * dt`, but your `v[1]` is 0, so your `x[1]` is also zero and then you get zeros throughout. Looks like one of those indices is supposed to be i-1?

Comment: In fact, I think it should be `x[i] += v[i-1]*dt` so that it increases its position relative to its prior position.

Comment: What formula are you trying to implement exactly?

Comment: you need to reference the previous index, but this formula still blows up to infinity quickly...

Answer (score 2):

Your equations to be solved are

dx/dt=v
dv/dt=-omega<sup>2</sup> x

If you combined these you would get the standard SHM equation

d<sup>2</sup>x/dt<sup>2</sup> = -omega<sup>2</sup> x

with natural circular frequency omega and period 2.pi / omega

Your timestep of dt=0.01 is FAR too large for the omega that you compute from that force constant. Instead you can change the whole length of the trace to 10 periods with

```
t = np.linspace(0, 10 * 2 * np.pi / omega, 1000)
```

Your update step was wrong (and first-order Euler isn't very good anyway).

```
#importing necessary libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#defining constants
x_0 = 1  #initial position
v_0 = 0  #initial velocity
m_sodium = 3.82e-26   #mass of sodium atom
k = 12.2  #force constant

#equation angular frequency 
omega = np.sqrt(k / m_sodium)

#creating an array for time
t = np.linspace(0, 10 * 2 * np.pi / omega, 1000)      # 10 oscillation periods

#initialising x and v arrays (to eventually hold the results)
x = np.zeros(len(t))
v = np.zeros(len(t))

#initial conditions
x[0] = x_0
v[0] = v_0

#defining time-step
dt = t[1] - t[0]

#Euler method to solve ODE for all the iterations  (THERE ARE BETTER METHODS)
for i in range(1, len(t)):    
    x[i] = x[i-1] + v[i-1] * dt
    v[i] = v[i-1] - omega**2 * x[i] * dt
                         
#plotting a graph x vs t
plt.plot(t, x)
plt.xlabel('Time t')
plt.ylabel('Position x')
plt.grid(True)
plt.title('Simple Harmonic Oscillator System')
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]